# reactjs - Testing Checkbox leads to a function call

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write a unit test for when a checkbox is checked, which would lead to a function being called. The React component is:

```
 const changeExamBoards = (e, filterOptions) => {
    if(e.target.checked && !(filterOptions.examBoards.includes(e.target.value))) {
        setfilterOptions({ ...filterOptions, examBoards: [...filterOptions.examBoards, e.target.value] });
    }
    else {
        setfilterOptions({ ...filterOptions, examBoards: [...filterOptions.examBoards.filter(item => item !== e.target.value)] });
    }
}; 
<div className='option-container' onChange={e => changeExamBoards(e, filterOptions)}>
                <div className='question-option-container'><input className='question-option' type="checkbox" name="AQA" value="AQA" /> AQA</div>
                <div className='question-option-container'><input className='question-option' type="checkbox" name="Edexcel" value="Edexcel" /> Edexcel</div>
                <div className='question-option-container'><input className='question-option' type="checkbox" name="OCR" value="OCR" /> OCR</div>
                <div className='question-option-container'><input className='question-option' type="checkbox" name="WJEC" value="WJEC" /> WJEC</div>
            </div>
```

The unit test I've been trying to run:

```
describe('QuestionFilter component', () => {
let store;
let wrapper;
let mockChangeExamBoards;
let mockRefreshPage;
let mockChangeDifficulty;

beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
        question: []
    });

    mockChangeExamBoards = jest.fn();
    mockRefreshPage = jest.fn();
    store.dispatch = jest.fn();
    mockChangeDifficulty = jest.fn();

    const mockProps = {
        store,
        refreshPage: mockRefreshPage,
        changeExamBoards: mockChangeExamBoards,
        changeDifficulty: mockChangeDifficulty
    }

    wrapper = mount(<QuestionFilter {...mockProps} />
    )
});



it('expect changeExamBoards to be called', () => {
    const eMock = { preventDefault: jest.fn(), target: 'fake target', checked: true };

    expect(mockChangeExamBoards).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    wrapper.find('.question-option-container')
        .at(0)
        .simulate('change', eMock);

    expect(mockChangeExamBoards).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However no matter how I try I keep getting this error:

```
QuestionFilter component › expect change difficulty to be called

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

I thought the simulate would call the mock function but nothing seems to actually call it?

Comment: Does your `onChange` working when you run the project? I thought `onChange` needed to be in the `<input>` tag, not in a `<div>`.... I am curious about how that is working.

Comment: Apart from my curiosity above, you are calling `change` in your input, but you don't really have an `onChange` listener on that input. That's why your mock function is not called. I feel like you should have separate `onChange` listeners for each `<input>`. It seems to be a cleaner code, IMO.

Comment: To answer your first question yes it does work, so all the checkboxes inside the div will call the 'changeExamBoards' function when changed. I tried putting the onChange inside the `<input>` and the inner `<div>` tags but unfortunately still the same issue

Comment: I see that `changeExamBoards` is a component method, but you test it as if it is passed as prop. I believe it would work if you do something like this: `onChange={e => this.props.changeExamBoards(e, filterOptions)}`

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to completely break the code. The actual code runs fine, it's just the unit testing that doesn't seem to work.